# I user Nuxt.js vue and the server some times down and get run time error

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have this error and I can't understand it
I user Nuxt.js vue
and the server some times down and get run time error:

```
   at SSRRenderer.renderResourceHints (C:\TestVueUI\node_modules\ (at SSRRenderer.renderResourceHints (C:\TestVueUI\node_modules\@nuxt\vue-renderer\dist\vue-renderer.js:3734:26)at SSRRenderer.renderResourceHints (C:\TestVueUI\node_modules\@nuxt\vue-renderer\dist\vue-renderer.js:3734:26): nuxt\vue-renderer\dist\vue-renderer.jsat SSRRenderer.renderResourceHints (C:\TestVueUI\node_modules\@nuxt\vue-renderer\dist\vue-renderer.js:3734:26): 3734)
   at SSRRenderer.render (C:\TestVueUI\node_modules\ (at SSRRenderer.render (C:\TestVueUI\node_modules\@nuxt\vue-renderer\dist\vue-renderer.js:3813:20)at SSRRenderer.render (C:\TestVueUI\node_modules\@nuxt\vue-renderer\dist\vue-renderer.js:3813:20): nuxt\vue-renderer\dist\vue-renderer.jsat SSRRenderer.render (C:\TestVueUI\node_modules\@nuxt\vue-renderer\dist\vue-renderer.js:3813:20): 3813)
   at process._tickCallback (at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7): internal/process/next_tick.jsat process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7): 68)
```